# IntelliJ + Gradle Multiproject: How to tell how the target source set is called?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

we are currently checking, whether we can switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ as an IDE.

In this project we are using gradle multi projects whose structure looks something like this:

```
Project
  |-ProjectA
    |-ProjectAImpl
      |-main*
    |-ProjectATest
      |-test*
  |-ProjectB
    |-ProjectBImpl
      |-main*
    |-ProjectBTest
      |-test*
```

- = Source set or in IntelliJ it seems a module.

The ProjectBTest has a dependency to ProjectATest, which is configured as

compile project(":ProjectA:ProjectATest")

This always worked properly with Eclipse but in IntelliJ I'm having the problem, that the ProjectBTest is configured such, that it is looking for a module named "Project.ProjectA.ProjectATest.main", instead of "Project.ProjectA.ProjectATest.**test**"
This module can obviously not be found, leading to a lot of compiler errors.

Can maybe somebody give me a hint how I can tell IntelliJ or gradle here to take the proper module?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Gradle functionality. Unless you have other Gradle customizations (like feature variants or changing the source directories for a source set), `project` dependencies will naturally target the `main` source set.

There are several ways to solve this, but two primary ones that stand out to me:

1. Use Gradle's [Java test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures).

   The "test" source set is not naturally inheritable in any way in Gradle. There is no built-in consumable [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) that provides test classes to downstream projects. However, Java test fixtures allow you to use a separate `testFixtures` source set which *is* shareable. To do this, you would do the following:

   1. Add the `java-test-fixtures` plugin to all projects which need to produce shared test sources
   2. Move your shared test sources to `<project directory>/src/testFixtures` (ideally this would include as few actual test classes as possible, but rather just shareable test logic instead)
   3. Change your dependency references to point to the upstream project(s)' test fixtures artifact: `testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":ProjectA:ProjectATest"))`
2. Register a `tests` configuration which includes the test classes as an output.

   ```
   project.configurations.register("tests") {
       extendsFrom(project.configurations[JavaPlugin.TEST_RUNTIME_CONFIGURATION_NAME])
   }
   tasks.register("testJar", Jar::class) {
       classifier.set("test-classes")
       from(project.the<SourceSetContainer>()[SourceSet.TEST_SOURCE_SET_NAME].output)
   }
   project.artifacts.add("tests", project.tasks.named("testJar"))
   ```

   Downstream projects:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile(project(":ProjectA:ProjectATest", "tests"))
   }
   ```

*None of the above code is tested. It may require some adjustments.*

Java test fixtures are a supported way to produce shareable test sources, so they should be preferred, but the `tests` configuration may be quicker to implement, depending on your use case.